# C++ Vector elements being replaced by last call to push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

So I have this code in my main function

```
if(mesType == 1) {
        cin.ignore();
        Message mes1;
        stack1.push(&mes1);
} else if(mesType == 2) {
        cin.ignore();
        MorseCodeMessage mes2;
        stack1.push(&mes2);
}
```

and here is the function

```
void MessageStack::push(Message *ms1) {
    messages.push_back(ms1);    
}
```

where messages is

```
vector <Message*> messages;
```

Can you explain why all the elements in my messages vector are being replaced by whatever I push last?

Comment: Do note that you are pushing pointers to your stack that immediately become dangling pointers. So you are storing pointers that are meaningless

Comment: You are pushing the address of a local variable that is destroyed after that. That’s a useless address, dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Well I need them to be pointers since I need my vector to be able to handle both types, since MorseCodeMessage is a child of the Message class and I'm using both in the vector

Comment: Than you need to allocate them on the free store. Read a good C++ book, you can’t learn C++ by trial and error.

Comment: @Caleblee Then you need them to be stored *somewhere* non-local. I recommend having your vector actually be a vector of `unique_ptr`, because there’s very little reason to do memory management manually in modern C++.

Comment: Okay thanks, just a college student learning C++ so I'm still new to everything in C++

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing pointers to local variables, which very likely yields undefined behaviour; if the local object has not gone out of scope, you have a chance to repeatedly push the address of the same object (local variable). Note that the content of the local variable will change, and all previously pushed addresses still point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing pointers to local variables that go out of scope after each push.  Stack space gets reused over time, so you likely end up with multiple pointers that are pointing at the same stack memory, but the pointers in the vector are technically dangling and using them is undefined behavior.

Since you clearly have polymorphic classes that derive from `Message`, you need to allocate them dynamically with `new` so they stay alive while stored in the vector:

```
if(mesType == 1) {
    cin.ignore();
    Message *mes1 = new Message;
    stack1.push(mes1);
} else if(mesType == 2) {
    cin.ignore();
    MorseCodeMessage *mes2 = new MorseCodeMessage;
    stack1.push(mes2);
}
```

Don't forget to define `Message` with a virtual destructor, and then call `delete` on each pointer when you are done using the vector, or when removing items from the vector.  Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

In C++11 and later, a safer solution is to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Message>> messages;

void MessageStack::push(std::unique_ptr<Message> ms1) {
    messages.push_back(std::move(ms1));
}

...

if(mesType == 1) {
    cin.ignore();
    stack1.push(std::unique_ptr<Message>(new Message));
    // or, in C++14 and later:
    //stack1.push(std::make_unique<Message>());
} else if(mesType == 2) {
    cin.ignore();
    stack1.push(std::unique_ptr<Message>(new MorseCodeMessage));
    // or, in C++14 and later:
    //stack1.push(std::make_unique<MorseCodeMessage>());
}
```